# What Regex do I use in Find/Replace to find all instances of a declaration string?

Tags: regex, visual-studio

I was handed some very badly written vb.Net code today and asked to migrate it to use ODP.Net.  To shortcut this a little, I used Find/Replace to set all of the command variables to `BindByName = true`. Based on the first few code files though, I though all of these were named "cmd".   Unfortunately, they aren't; the original author of the code actually named all of their commands after their purpose, even though they only used one `OracleCommand` per function. They also decided that `using` was apparently not worth doing, either.

```
Dim cmGetStatus As New OracleCommand
cmGetStatus.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd.BindByName = True `<--this was added by my previous replace with a regex
```

What regex could I use to grab all instances of "Dim ____ as New OracleCommand" and replace the variable name with "cmd"?  What about the same sort of replacement on all instances of "_____.CommandType"?  This would save me at least 8 hours of manual edits.

Comment: You can do it with one regex in Notepad++. Not in VS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search: (Dim ).*( As New OracleCommand)

Replace: $1cmd$2

Search: .*( = CommandType.StoredProcedure)

Replace: cmd$1

Group replacements are done with $1, $2, etc.

Comment: Couldn't this theoretically be done in one regex?  I'm not at all familiar with VS regex replace, but could something like `/(Dim\s+)?cm\w+(.*New\s+OracleCommand|\.CommandType\s+=\s+CommandType\.StoredProcedure)/` work?  Replace would still be `$1cmd$2`.

Comment: Absolutely! Also, I threw in spaces there, assuming spaces were exactly the same everywhere. That might not be the case too. I kept it as simple as possible, but the regex is totally flexible.

Comment: @JosephMarikle everyone always wants to combine their whole complicated task into one regex.  Why?  It's usually clearer and less error-prone to go with a simpler multi-step process.

Comment: @dan1111 I'm not sure entirely.  I guess I just don't feel like doing a lot of copy and pasting of multiple expressions and repetitively hitting the button? I suppose it's typical developer laziness.  Laziness is sort of the mother of all scripting. :P

Comment: This worked, but I did have to keep it separate.  There were instances where code was commented out or variable names contained positive results from the regex and running these separately was helpful.